# Delete the last remaining node in a link list

Tags: c++

I am making this function that deletes an element inside of a list. The problem is when I delete the **last remaining node** of the list it gives me back nothing. To be precise, let's say we have a link list

head -> node_1 -> node_2 -> NULL

I want to delete all of the items inside the list hence " head -> NULL; "

```
void delete_item(NODE **start,int *last){
    NODE *before, *discard;
    int delete_value;

    if(is_empty(*start) == 1){
        cout << endl << "THE LIST IS EMPTY";
    }else{

        discard = *start;

        print_items(*start);

        cout << endl << "What item would you like to delete?: ";
        cin >> delete_value; 

        if((*start)->next == NULL){
            cout << endl <<"entered" << endl;

            delete *start;
            *start = NULL;

            --*last;
        }

        //if delete value is in the first node
        if((*start)->value == delete_value){

            *start = (*start)->next;
            (*start)->prev = NULL;
            free(discard);
            --*last;
            cout << endl << "ITEM SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!";

        }else{
            int index{1};

            //searches for the value 
            while(discard != NULL && discard->value != delete_value){
                before = discard;
                discard = discard->next;
                ++index;
            }

            if(discard == NULL){
                cout << endl<< "ITEM DOES NOT EXIST TRY AGAIN!" << endl;

            }else{

                //if item is in the last node of the list
                if(index == *last){

                    before->next = NULL;
                    free(discard);
                    --*last;
                    cout << endl << "ITEM SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!" << endl;

                }else{

                //if item is in between the list
                    discard->next->prev = before->next;
                    before->next = discard->next;
                    free(discard);
                    --*last;
                    cout << endl << "ITEM SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!" << endl;

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're making this *much* harder than it need be. First, the actual delete operation should be its own function,taking the address of the list head pointer, the value to delete, and apparently a node counter address as arguments. The user-interaction should be in a separate function. Then your much simpler `delete_item` will simply march `start` down the list until it finds the node to delete (or not) and excise it (or not). Short version: break your problem down further.

Comment: I just figured it out finally! Turns out separating the user-interaction helped me understand the code better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to delete a given node in a seperate function and then call that function according to your requirement. You can find that kind of code in any coding website.

However, I did not want to discourage your method. So I am editing your code only.

```
void delete_item(NODE **start,int *last){
    NODE *before, *discard;
    int delete_value;

    if(is_empty(*start) == 1){
        cout << endl << "THE LIST IS EMPTY";
    }else{

        discard = *start;

        print_items(*start);

        cout << endl << "What item would you like to delete?: ";
        cin >> delete_value; 


        //if delete value is in the first node
        if((*start)->value == delete_value){

            *start = (*start)->next;
            (*start)->prev = NULL;
            free(discard);
            --*last;
            cout << endl << "ITEM SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!";

        }else{
            int index{1};

            //searches for the value 
            while(discard != NULL && discard->value != delete_value){
                before = discard;
                discard = discard->next;
                ++index;
            }

            if(discard == NULL){
                cout << endl<< "ITEM DOES NOT EXIST TRY AGAIN!" << endl;

            }else{

                //if item is in the last node of the list
                if(index == *last){

                    before->next = NULL;
                    free(discard);
                    --*last;
                    cout << endl << "ITEM SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!" << endl;

                }else{

                //if item is in between the list
                    discard->next->prev = before;
                    before->next = discard->next;
                    free(discard);
                    --*last;
                    cout << endl << "ITEM SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!" << endl;

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working bro thanks a lot for the advice much appreciated!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider making it as the correct answer.